# Find if a value in a cell exists in another range/cell

Tags: vba, excel

I need a piece of code that takes the value from a cell and checks another column for that value and then returns a true/false answer or similar.

Then I will use a conditional to say something like

```
If "Value in cell B1" exists in Column C Then

Do nothing

Else

Msgbox "Please enter existing/valid value in B1"

End if
```

I simply cannot figure out how to do this. Thanks in advance for any help!

Rgards
Jim

Comment: Take a look at the Match Function. It will be able to do what you want.

Comment: Use excels find function....or match....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Range.Find` to do this.

```
Dim rng as Range
Set rng = Range("C:C").Find(What:=Range("B1").Value), _
                              LookIn:=xlValues, _
                              LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                              SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                              MatchCase:=False) 
If rng is nothing Then
    Msgbox "Please enter existing/valid value in B1"
Else
    ' value of b1 found in column C
    ' do something else
End If
```

This will check whether the value of cell B1 is in any cell of column C.

The `rng` variable will point to the first occurence of the b1 value in column C.

More about all parameters of `.find` can be found at msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff839746.aspx

Comment: Looks very similar to what Matt Webb above said. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: Actually, I was first. You can see that "answered XX minutes ago". So it would be fair to support my answer...

Comment: Oh dear. Sorry about that. Ive changed. I thought they showed up in chonological order.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this should work. Insert into a new module in your VBA editor, then use the custom function in a `Worksheet` like so:

`=find_string(B1,C:C)`

```
Function Find_String(ByVal SearchTerm As String, ByVal Rng As Range) As String
    Dim FindString As String

    If Trim(SearchTerm) <> "" Then
        With Rng
           Set Rng = .Find(What:=SearchTerm, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
           If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

                'Do something!

                'Examples:
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                Find_String = "Found in cell " + Rng.Address

            Else
                MsgBox "Please enter existing/valid value in B1"
                Find_String = "Nothing Found"
            End If
        End With
    End If

End Function
```